# When Using NetworkStream data not recieved over basic tcp interface

Tags: c#, tcp

I'm creating a basic TicTacToe program to play against my friends across the internet (this is to learn the basics of network programming). The problem is that although the correct data is received by the client, when it tries to send data no data is sent, even though the code executes correctly.

Here is the client software:

```
string input;
Board board = new Board();
while (true)
{
    TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
    tcpclnt.Connect("192.168.0.10", 5000);

    byte[] b = new byte[1024];

    NetworkStream ns = tcpclnt.GetStream();

    int k = ns.Read(b, 0, 100);//recieve data from host
    string sRecieve = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        sRecieve += Convert.ToChar(b[i]);

    Console.WriteLine(sRecieve);

    input = Console.ReadLine();

    ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(input);

    ns.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);
    tcpclnt.Close();
}
```

This is the server code (this is all that is running when the connection occurs):

```
    TcpListener tcpList = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
    tcpList.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for valid connection");
    Socket s = tcpList.AcceptSocket();
    Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from: " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

    ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
    s.Send(asen.GetBytes(board.ToString()));//send data
    Console.WriteLine("sent board layout");

    byte[] b = new byte[1024];

    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for next play");
    int k = s.Receive(b);
    Console.WriteLine("Received next play");

    string sInput = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        input += Convert.ToChar(b[i]);
```

Comment: You have waaay too many things wrong with your code. Probably the issue most directly related to your issue is that you close the client immediately after sending, without using `Shutdown()` and most likely before anything has been transmitted, resetting the socket and preventing the data from being sent. But you've made lots of other "socket newbie" mistakes here too. You should _carefully_ read a good tutorial and the [Winsock FAQ](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/), where you will find all the information you need to know how to correctly write a networked program.

Comment: Ok thanks this is useful to know